# Rubymotion Enterprise Release

Tags: ios, rubymotion, ad-hoc-distribution, enterprise-distribution

How does one release to a staging environment or create a release for Enterprise/Ad Hoc distribution?

This is different from an AppStore release and requires a different provisioning profile, and optionally a different bundle id.

Comment: Looks like it is written here in the docs -> http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/#_build (Section 6.3)

Comment: @borrrden So I should run `rake archive` then use the same ipa and submit for enterprise distribution?

Comment: That's what it says, just make sure you are using the correct profile  / certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a conditional in your `Rakefile` and make sure that you have all the correct certificates and provisioning profiles for each type of build you want.

```
  app.release do    
    if ENV['staging'] == "true"
      app.codesign_certificate = "iPhone Distribution: Your Company's Enterprise Certificate"
      app.provisioning_profile = "distribution/Enterprise.mobileprovision"
      app.identifier = "com.yourcompany.appnameenterprise"
    else
      app.codesign_certificate = "iPhone Distribution: Your Company's App Store Release Certificate"
      app.provisioning_profile = "distribution/AppStore.mobileprovision"
      app.identifier = "com.yourcompany.appname"
    end
  end
```

To set up the staging `ENV` variable I have another rake task that sets it:

```
task :set_staging do
  ENV['staging'] = "true"
end
```

Then to actually release:

```
desc "Release Enterprise build"
task :enterprise_release => [
  :set_staging,
  "archive:distribution",
]
```